# Understanding Vigenere cipher in Haskell

Tags: haskell, vigenere

I'm having trouble understanding what's exactly going on in the code below.

Specifically the recursive function call and "ks++[k]" as well as the chr $ 65. I'm assuming the former is used for recursively iterating through the list, but if someone could explain like i'm 5 I'd be very grateful.

```
vig (p:ps) (k:ks) = (encrypt p k):(vig ps (ks++[k])) 
  where
    encrypt b = chr $ 65 + mod (ord a + ord b) 26
```

full code

```
vig :: [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char]
vig [] k = []
vig p [] = []
vig (p:ps) (k:ks) = (encrypt p k):(vig ps (ks++[k]))
  where
    encrypt a b = chr $ 65 + mod (ord a + ord b) 26
```

Comment: Possibly not relevant, but what is `a` in the definition of `encrypt`?

Comment: @chepner oh it's a typo, sry

Comment: It *looks* like the `k`-list is expected to be shorter than the `p`-list (how is `vig` defined when one or both arguments are empty lists?), so `ks ++ [k]` is just a way to cycle through the `k`'s until the `p`'s are exhausted.

Comment: Rather than constantly appending like this, something like `vig ps ks = vig' ps (cycle ks) where vig' (p:ps) (k:ks) = encrypt p k : vig ps ks` would be more efficient.

Comment: I edited in the full code for clarity, and thank you that helps. I'm new to haskell and everything is still confusing hah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that each character in the first list is "shifted" by a distance determined by the corresponding character in the second list. The second list, though, may have a different length than the first. If it is longer, there's no problem; you'll just ignore the extra (as seen by the base case `vig [] k = []`). If it is *shorter*, though, you'll want to start over at the beginning.

Suppose you start with the call `vig "horse" "dog"`. Then you will make the following recursive calls in order:

```
vig "orse" "ogd"
vig "rse" "gdo"
vig "se" "dog"
vig "e" "ogd"
vig "" "gdo"
```

`encrypt` is what does the actual encryption; it returns a new character based on the character `p` from the message and the character `k` from the encryption `k`. Each message character is used exactly once; each key character could be used multiple times (if the key is shorter than the message) or not at all (if the key is longer).

A simpler (and more efficient way) to do this is to use the `cycle` function to create an infinite, repeating list from the key. (If `ks` is already long enough, it just makes an even longer list of characters you'll ultimately ignore. Because Haskell is lazy, there is no cost for this simplifying abstraction.)

```
vig ps ks = vig' ps (cycle ks)
  where vig' _ [] = p
        vig' [] _ = []
        vig' (p:ps) (k:ks) = encrypt p k : vig' ps ks
        encrypt a b = ...
```

However, `vig'` doesn't really care about the contents of either list or what `encrypt` does. It's kind of like `map`, except instead of building one list from another by apply a function to each element, it builds one list from *two* lists by applying a function to each corresponding pair of elements. This pattern is predefined as the `zipWith` function.

```
vig ps ks = zipWith encrypt ps ks  -- vig = zipWith encrypt
  where encrypt a b = ...
```